# Mailto action with explorer 9 - blank email

Tags: html, internet-explorer, outlook, mailto

I have an html form that I'm sending to external customers so they can fill up and send it back to me.
The problem occurs when they click the submit button on the form.

For some reason in windows 7 64 bit, with outlook 2010 and explorer 9, mailto action doesn't work for me.
An empty outlook message is displayed and only the subject and recipients are added.
There is no attachment and no body text.
When I change the default browser to FF I receive the text I wanted in the body section instead as an attachment (postdata.att).
I can't use server code cause the html form is sent by outlook to external customers, so asp/php/cgi is irrelevant for me.
The external customers have no access to the organization's intranet and since the html form is sent as an email attachment, it's also not hosted on an internet server.

Does anyone has a solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> mailto action doesn't work for me.

mailto depends on specific combinations of correctly configured browsers and email clients. It is not suitable for pubic use in an action attribute as support is too poor.

Use a server side process instead. Note that form support in HTML email is also poor, so you should link to a form hosted on the web.

> I can't use server code cause the html form is sent by outlook to external customers, so asp/php/cgi is irrelevant for me.

You need to set up a public facing webserver.

Comment: Unfortunately as I mentioned, I really can't use a server side code.
What about CDO? Can I use it as a solution?
I read somewhere that microsoft doesn't support this technology with outlook 2010.
Is there some sort of a replacement for the CDO protocol?

Comment: End user email clients do not support running third party scripts that are embedded in emails. Server side code is the only option that will work, and it is a problem that your organisation can solve by investing in a public facing web server.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Can you please explain a bit more regarding your suggestion? I'm am talking about a VB software that was developed in house and has VB forms in it. one of the software's features is to export a form to an html form and send it through the outlook to external customer which also uses outlook. Can I maybe write a code to export the form to a public facing web server and then send a link on mail? there can be hundred of forms sent to different customers on a daily basis.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I had no problem with sending them the form via mail, my problem was when they clicked on the submit button and tried to send the data back. they received a blank email with no postdata.att attachment. and this only happens when we use IE9.

Comment: I'm now completely lost. Who is using the system when it breaks? Is the form they are using a VB WinForm, an HTML form in a webpage or an HTML form in an email? Are the people using the system on a controlled system or are they members of the public?

Comment: our software is a VB win-form software. one of the features is to convert the VB win-form into a simple HTML file and send it as an attachment in an email. The external customers open the HTML form and submit it. in the HTML form they submit, there is a mailto action and it's suppose to send an email back to us. In this exact point the system breaks. Whren they click the submit button, a new blank email in outlook 2010 is opened. the customers opened the html form they received with IE9 and tried to submit it. They can see the correct recipients and subject, but the mail is empty!

Comment: When they used IE8, the mail that was sent back to us contained an attachment with the name POSTDATA.ATT and our VB software had no problem reading it and updating the DB accordingly. I just need to do something to return the attachment back to the mail they are trying to send me. the people which receive the html form in mail are customers of companies we work with. They all have outlook but we have no shared network with them.

Comment: OK. HTML document, containing a form, loaded from the local file system, in a browser. I think you'll find you have security lock downs with anything regarding ActiveX/CDO/etc. (Even if you can guarantee that the customers are Windows/IE/Outlook).

Comment: *Can I maybe write a code to export the form to a public facing web server and then send a link on mail?* — Yes. I'd set up a webserver that the VB app can interact with. It authenticates with the service and submits the data. The service then either returns a unique id to the VB app which then sends the email or the service sends the email itself. The email contains a link with that unique ID in it. The customers can then open it and the web server will generate the HTML form based on the data submitted by the VM app (which would be associated with that unique id).